# Eigenpairs of $XX^T$ via SVD

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

In class, my professor mentioned the following technique as a fast way to compute the eigenpairs of a fat matrix (a matrix where the number of columns is much greater than the number of rows).

> For an input matrix $X$ of dimensions $m\times n$, where $n$ is very large, compute $B=XX^T$.
>
> Compute the SVD of $B$

Am I correct in understanding that by finding the eigenpairs of a matrix $B=XX^T$, we also find the eigenpairs of $X$; that is, the eigenpairs of $X$ and $XX^T$ are the same?

If so, why is this the case?

Comment: The notion of "eigenpair" doesn't make sense for a "fat" matrix.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm making a horrible misunderstanding, but isn't an eigenpair just the pair of eigenvalue-eigenvector? Why can a fat matrix not have an eigenpair?

Comment: Eigenvectors are only defined for square matrices. A matrix is also a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces. Square matrices map these vector spaces into themselves.Rectangular matrices are maps between spaces of different dimensions. An eigenvector is a vector where the action of the linear map is just scaling. For that to even make sense, the input and output of the map have to be in the same vector space.

Comment: I see... I have a greater misunderstanding then. I'll have to clarify with my professor what he meant.

Comment: He's probably referring to the SVD of X, which is indeed related to the SVD of B. Notice that B is is $m \times m$.

Comment: I see... so B's eigenvector decomposition ($B=USV^TVS^TU^T=US^2U^T$) can be used to find B's eigenvectors, which are equivalent X's left singular vectors, which can be used to find X's right singular vectors. Is that correct?

Comment: And X's singular values would be the square root of B's eigenvalues.

Comment: At most $m$ of $X$'s singular values are nonzero, so doing this gives all the nonzero singular values. $U$, $S$, and the first $m$ columns of $V$ are all you really need.